# Connect 4 Python 3 - Declaring Global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was programming a simple Connect 4 game however I need to add global variables

```
    # Board(0:6, 0:7) : str (but ignore row 0 and column
    0)
    # ThisPlayer : str[1]
    # GameFinished, WinnerFound : bool
    # ColumnNumber : int
    # ValidColumn, ValidRow : int
```

which im stuck on as I cant remember how to define global booleans etc (global variables are above)
when I run the code it gives me the error code (Board is not defined) how can I add the global variables so my program runs ?
Code is below

```
        Board[0:6][0:7] 
        Blank = '.'

        def InititialiseBoard():
            Board = [[Blank for i in range(7)]
                     for j in range(6)]


        def SetUpGame():
            ThisPlayer = 'o'
            GameFinished = False

        def OutputBoard():
            for Row in range(6 , 0 , -1):
                for Column in range(7):
                    print(Board[Row][Column] , end = '')
                print()

        def ColumnNumberValud():
            Valid = False
            if ColumnNumber >= 1 and CalumnNumber <= 7:
                if Board[6][ColumnNumber] ==  Blank:
                    Valid = True
            return Valid


        def ThisPlayerChoosesColumn():
            print('Player ' + ThisPlayer + ' turn.')
            while ColumnNumberValid == False:
                print('Enter Valid Column Number')
                ColumnNumber = int(input('Enter Column Number: '))
            return ColumnNumber


        def ThisPlayerMakesMove():
            ValidColumn = ThisPlayerChoosesColumn()
            ValidRow = FindNextFreePositionInColumn()
            Board[ValidRow][ValidColumn] = ThisPlayer


        def FindNextFreePositionInColumn():
            ThisRow = 1
            while Board[ThisRow][ValidColumn] != Blank:
                ThisRow = ThisRow + 1
            return ThisRow

        def CheckHorizontalLineInValidRow():
            for i in range(4):
                if Board[ValidRow][i] == ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow][i+1] == ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow][i+2] == ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow][i+3] == ThisPlayer:
                    WinnerFound = True

        def CheckVerticalLineInValidRow():
            if ValidRow == 4 or ValidRow == 5 or ValidRow == 6:
                if Board[ValidRow][ValidColumn] ==  ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow - 1][ValidColumn] == ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow - 2][ValidColumn] == ThisPlayer and Board[ValidRow - 3 ][ValidColumn] == ThisPlayer:
                    WinnerFound = True
        def CheckForFullBoard():
            BlankFound = False
            ThisRow = 0
            while ThisRow !=6 or BlankFound == False:
                ThisColumn = 0
                ThisRow = ThisRow + 1
                while ThisColumn != 7 or BlankFound == True:
                    ThisColumn = ThisColumn + 1
                    if Board[ThisRow][ThisColumn] == Blank:
                        BlankFound = True
            if Blankfound == False:
                print('Draw')
                GameFinished = True

        def CheckIfThisPlayerHasWon():
            WinnerFound = False
            CheckHorizontalLineInValidRow()
            if WinnerFound == False:
                CheckVerticalLineInValidColumn()
            if WinnerFound == True:
                GameFinished = True
                print(ThisPlayer , 'Winner')
            else:
                CheckForFullBoard()
```

Answer (score 1):

To use global variables:

```
global x
x = 1
def foo():
    global x
    x+=1
print(x)
foo()
print(x)
```

I would recommend avoiding global variables and use class variables instead.

```
class yourclass():
    def__init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    def foo(self):
        self.x+=1
    def print_value(self):
        print(self.x)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test = yourclass()
    test.print_value()
    test.foo()
    test.print_value()
```